# Apply the same operation to multiple aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a StockLine aggregate. It shows what product resides on which location in a warehouse and in which quantity. Now on UI I am able to select one stock line and reserve some quantity. Later on we need to implement multiselect of the stocklines and reserve them. Lets say I selected 2 aggregates, and I want to reserve both of them. What is the best way of doing this, taking in consideration that I already have implemented a usecase to reserve 1 aggregate.
1) foreach selected aggregate call BackEnd's ReserveStockLine one by one...
2) send just one command with Ids of the selected aggregates and treat it as a totally separate usecase. If its a separate usecase I should return some ReservationResult with the result of reservation foreach aggregate? Cause it might be smbdy else is reserving the same aggregate and its not enough quantity already (cause the quantity user sees on UI is not a real quantity). My requirement is to reserve as much as possible. If one fails I don't have to roll back the others...Thinking about how to show this process interactively on UI. Maybe some checkboxes, that are showing how stocklines are getting reserved one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> send just one command with Ids of the selected aggregates and treat it as a totally separate usecase.

This is a common approach.  You "just" iterate over the ids, and update each aggregate one at a time.

In the happy path, this is relatively straight forward.

To avoid contention, you may end up needing to update each aggregate in its own transaction.

In the happy path, things are relatively straight forward.  But when you start to consider failures (what happens if the app crashes in the middle), then things get more challenging.  You'll likely need to ensure that the updates to the aggregates are idempotent, so that you can safely repeat a lost command.